# Create trigger to update balance after transactions from an account and to an account - SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Could someone help me here? I'm trying to create a trigger that updates balance in ACCOUNT table after transactions from the TRANSFERS table. The whole table model is bigger, but here are two of them:

```
--ACCOUNT--
CREATE TABLE account(
account_num NUMBER(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ktnr REFERENCES account_type(ktnr),
regdate DATE NOT NULL,
balance NUMBER(10,2));

--TRANSFERS--
CREATE TABLE transfers(
row_nr NUMBER(9) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
pers_nr REFERENCES customer(pers_nr),
from_account_num REFERENCES account(account_num),
to_account_num REFERENCES account(account_num),
amount NUMBER(10,2),
date DATE NOT NULL);
```

And the code I think is quite wrong but that's the idea of solution. Not sure how to write it in a better way.

```
create or replace trigger aifer_transfers
 after insert
 on transfers
 for each row
 when (new.amount is not null)
begin
  if :new.to_account_num != :new.pers_nr then
    update account a
    set a.balance = a.balance - :new.amount
    where :old.account_num = :new:account_num;

    elsif 
    :new.to_account_num = :new.pers_nr  then
    update account a
    set a.balance = a.balance + :new.amount
    where :old.account_num = :new:account_num;
    end if; 
 end;
```

Many different errors, depending on chosen variables:
Line/Col: 3/9 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line/Col: 5/26 PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW'

Comment: Sorry, there were some mistakes in my code as it was translated to English. I edited it, should make more sense.

Comment: `:new:account_num` should, presumably, be `:new.account_num`.   It's not a syntax error but I can't imagine that you want your `where` clauses to compare the `:old` and `:new` values of `account_num`.  I'd wager that you want the `where` clause to be `a.account_num = :new.account_num`.  I can't see how your `if` statement makes sense logically-- why would the `to_account_num`, which references the `account` table ever match the `pers_nr` column which references the `customer` table?

Comment: On `insert` statement `:old` is always [empty](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDDDG/tdddg_triggers.htm#TDDDG99934).

Comment: @JustinCave The `transfers` table does not have an `account_num` column.

Comment: Thanks. I'm very new with SQL, that's why I'm making a lot of mistakes. Not sure how to solve this anyway.   I tried  before a.account_num = :new.account_num -> Line/Col: 10/23 PLS-00049: bad bind variable.

Comment: @Baibs As i said in my previous comment; the `transfers` table does not have an `account_num` table so using `:NEW.account_num` is not going to work (you get the `PLS-00049` exception). You can only reference the columns of the table you have inserted into (i.e. `transfers`) with the `:NEW` bind variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your table declarations are missing some data types (since we don't have your other tables) and, from Oracle 12, you can use `IDENTITY` columns for the primary keys (and have some `CHECK` constraints and `DEFAULT` values for `DATE` columns):

```sql
CREATE TABLE account(
  account_num NUMBER(8,0)
              GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
              NOT NULL
              CONSTRAINT account__account_num__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  ktnr        NUMBER(8,0)
              -- CONSTRAINT account__ktnr__fk REFERENCES account_type(ktnr)
              ,
  regdate     DATE
              DEFAULT SYSDATE
              NOT NULL,
  balance     NUMBER(10,2)
              NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE transfers(
  row_nr           NUMBER(9)
                   GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                   NOT NULL
                   CONSTRAINT transfers__row_nr__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  pers_nr          NUMBER(8,0)
                   NOT NULL
                   -- CONSTRAINT transfers__pers_nr__fk REFERENCES customer(pers_nr)
                   ,
  from_account_num NOT NULL
                   CONSTRAINT transfers_from__fk REFERENCES account(account_num),
  to_account_num   NOT NULL
                   CONSTRAINT transfers__to__fk REFERENCES account(account_num),
  amount           NUMBER(10,2)
                   NOT NULL
                   CONSTRAINT transfers__amount_chk CHECK ( amount > 0 ),
  datetime         DATE
                   DEFAULT SYSDATE
                   NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT transfers__from_ne_to__chk CHECK ( from_account_num != to_account_num )
);
```

Then you can create the trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER aifer_transfers
AFTER INSERT ON TRANSFERS
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE account
  SET   balance = CASE account_num
                  WHEN :NEW.from_account_num
                  THEN balance - :NEW.amount
                  WHEN :NEW.to_account_num
                  THEN balance + :NEW.amount
                  ELSE balance
                  END
  WHERE account_num IN ( :new.from_account_num, :new.to_account_num );
END;
/
```

If you create 3 accounts:

```sql
INSERT INTO account ( ktnr, balance ) VALUES ( 0, 100 );
INSERT INTO account ( ktnr, balance ) VALUES ( 0, 100 );
INSERT INTO account ( ktnr, balance ) VALUES ( 0, 100 );
```

Then after:

```sql
INSERT INTO transfers (
  pers_nr, from_account_num, to_account_num, amount
) VALUES (
  0, 1, 2, 20
);
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM account;
```

Outputs:

> | ACCOUNT_NUM | KTNR | REGDATE | BALANCE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 0 | 18-MAY-21 | 80 |
> | 2 | 0 | 18-MAY-21 | 120 |
> | 3 | 0 | 18-MAY-21 | 100 |

Then after:

```sql
INSERT INTO transfers (
  pers_nr, from_account_num, to_account_num, amount
) VALUES (
  0, 1, 3, 15
);
```

It would be:

> | ACCOUNT_NUM | KTNR | REGDATE | BALANCE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 0 | 18-MAY-21 | 65 |
> | 2 | 0 | 18-MAY-21 | 120 |
> | 3 | 0 | 18-MAY-21 | 115 |

Then after:

```sql
INSERT INTO transfers ( pers_nr, from_account_num, to_account_num, amount )
SELECT 0, 3, 2, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 2, 3, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 1, 2, 10 FROM DUAL;
```

It would be:

> | ACCOUNT_NUM | KTNR | REGDATE | BALANCE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 0 | 18-MAY-21 | 55 |
> | 2 | 0 | 18-MAY-21 | 120 |
> | 3 | 0 | 18-MAY-21 | 125 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b7c592ba5b52e765a11f8b19adda5c55)*

---

## Update

For your tables, without any additional `CHECK` constraints, you may want:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER aifer_transfers
AFTER INSERT ON TRANSFERS
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.amount <= 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20000, 'Amount must be above zero.' );
  END IF;
  IF :NEW.from_account_num IS NULL THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20000, 'From account must be non-null.' );
  END IF;
  IF :NEW.to_account_num IS NULL THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20000, 'To account must be non-null.' );
  END IF;
  IF :NEW.from_account_num = :NEW.to_account_num THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20000, 'Accounts must be different.' );
  END IF;
  UPDATE account
  SET   balance = CASE account_num
                  WHEN :NEW.from_account_num
                  THEN balance - :NEW.amount
                  WHEN :NEW.to_account_num
                  THEN balance + :NEW.amount
                  ELSE balance
                  END
  WHERE account_num IN ( :new.from_account_num, :new.to_account_num );
END;
/
```

*(But that validation should all be implemented as `CHECK` constraints on the `transfers` table rather than in a trigger.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0c38b90fc486cd009c6607c960f198e7)*

Comment: This looks great! But as it is a school assignment I'm afraid that I can't change the table code. Also, I have other 13 connected assignments (trigges, procerures and functions) based on the current code.

Comment: @Baibs There are 4 (I think) things different about the tables (other than identity columns) and they are all `NOT NULL` or `CHECK` constraints. If you want to move checking those into the `WHERE` clause of the trigger then you can but otherwise the answer still stands using the original tables.

Comment: @Baibs [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1fa14ff942ffdb6f74e51d27c14e0158) The only thing changed in the DDL for the table was to use double-quotes around the `DATE` identifier as it is a keyword; other than the answer works for your tables. The only change to the `TRIGGER` was to move the things that should be checked in `CHECK` constraint on the `transfers` table into checks in the trigger's `WHEN` clause.